# React datepicker - invalid time value

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am trying to create a React-datepicker; however, I am getting this error:

> RangeError: Invalid Time Value

I added a **dateFormat** to match my date variable; however, I am still getting the same error?

What am I doing wrong?

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

let date = moment(dateString).format('MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a'); // January 3, 2019 12:30 pm

<DatePicker
    selected={date}
    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
    showTimeSelect
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    timeIntervals={15}
    dateFormat="MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a"
    timeCaption="time"
/>
```

I have tried **dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"** as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `DatePicker` expects a `Date`, not a `moment`. You have to convert it first:

```
let date = moment(dateString).toDate();
```

From the DatePicker [docs](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker#momentjs):

> Up until version 1.8.0, this package was using Moment.js. Starting v2.0.0, we switched to using native Date objects to reduce the size of the package. If you're switching from 1.8.0 to 2.0.0 or higher, please see the updated example above of check out the examples site for up to date examples.

Comment: Thank you. That was the exact problem I was having!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the issue involved checking whether the Date was null after pulling the Date in ISO format from the database.

```
 <DatePicker selected={initiated_Date ? new Date(initiated_Date) : null}
```